# Improve performance of mapping values

Tags: java, java-stream

I have the following code. I would like to know if I can improve the performance of the following code.

```
class CarModel {
    private long carKey;
    private String carName;
    private CarColor carColor;
    private CarEngine carEngine;
}

class CarColor {
    private long carKey;
    private String carPrimaryColor;
    private String carSecondaryColor;
}

class CarEngine {
    private long carKey;
    private String carEnginePartNumber;
    private String carEngineTransmissionFluid;
}
```

I am getting values for CarModel class from database which has only carKey and carName.
Then I get values for CarColor and carEngine and perform some data transformation on those lists and then assign the values to the CarModel so that I can update tables on the database.

The mapping of values to the CarModel is done in the following way

```
private void addList(List<?> list, List<CarModel> carModelList) {
    carModelList.stream().forEach(x -> {
        for (Object object : list) {
            if (object instanceof CarColor
                    && ((CarColor) object).getCarKey() == x.getCarKey()) {
                x.setCarColor(((CarColor) object));
                break;
            }
            if (object instanceof CarEngine
                    && ((CarEngine) object).getCarKey() == x.getCarKey()) {
                x.setCarEngine(((CarEngine) object));
                break;
            }
        }
    });
}
```

The above code works. Is there any way I can improve the code in addList() method and make it run faster?

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks you

Answer (score 1):

Yes, by storing the `CarColor` and `CarEngine` objects in a Map data structure with their `carKey` as the key.

Then, rather than repeatedly checking the list, the necessary `CarColor` or `CarEngine` object from the Map may be retrieved to perform the mapping of values to the `CarModel`.

This would significantly lower the time complexity from O(n2) to O(n).

Something like:

```
void addList(List<?> list, List<CarModel> carModelList) {
    Map<Long, CarColor> colorMap = new HashMap<>();
    Map<Long, CarEngine> engineMap = new HashMap<>();

    for (Object object : list) {
        if (object instanceof CarColor) {
            CarColor color = (CarColor) object;
            colorMap.put(color.getCarKey(), color);
        }
        if (object instanceof CarEngine) {
            CarEngine engine = (CarEngine) object;
            engineMap.put(engine.getCarKey(), engine);
        }
    }

    carModelList.forEach(x -> {
        CarColor color = colorMap.get(x.getCarKey());
        if (color != null) {
            x.setCarColor(color);
        }
        CarEngine engine = engineMap.get(x.getCarKey());
        if (engine != null) {
            x.setCarEngine(engine);
        }
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

For each element of `carModelList` you iterate the complete `list` once, meaning you'll have *n* * *m* inner loop iterations where `n` is the size of `carModelList` and `m` is the size of list.

Instead of looping over `carModelList`, it would be much faster to build a `Map<Long,CarModel>` (that you probably want to keep around in the long term, possibly *instead of* `carModelList`) and just lookup the `CarModel` object using the objects `carKey`, thus eliminating the outer loop entirely.

Answer (score 0):

One way to improve the performance of this code is to use a Map instead of a List to store the information in the "list" parameter. The key of the map could be the "carKey" and the value could be either a "CarColor" or a "CarEngine". Then, you could use the "get" method of the map to retrieve the information for each "CarModel" in the "carModelList". This would eliminate the need to iterate through the entire list for each "CarModel".

Here's the updated code:

```java
private void addList(Map<Integer, Object> map, List<CarModel> carModelList) {
  carModelList.stream().forEach(x -> {
    Object object = map.get(x.getCarKey());
    if (object instanceof CarColor) {
     x.setCarColor((CarColor) object);
   } else if (object instanceof CarEngine) {
     x.setCarEngine((CarEngine) object);
  }
  });
}
```

Comment: This implies that a CarModel can have either a color or an engine, but not both…

Comment: you can adapt your hashmap to your specific needs, store two values(an array for example ) for a key, and get the information needed. The hashmap will be faster in any case. Otherwise, you can use parallel streams of Java, but you have to ensure it helps.